# Are Java methods storing copies of values?

Tags: java, c

> I have been learning C and now I want to compare it to Java

If I do this

```
void changeVal(int x){
    ++x;
}
```

in **C** that only changes the value of `x` stored in the stack frame. It changes the local copy of `x`only.

So what does

```
int x = 5;
public void changeValJava(int x){
    ++x; 
}
```

do in **Java?**

Does it change the value of `x` or the value of an instance of `x`?

In **C** we would need to use a pointer to `x` to change the actual value, but what about in Java?

Comment: Java uses pass-by-value. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) answer in StackOverflow.

Comment: You have asked 8 questions on SO so far. You received answers to most of them. Were they *all* not helpful to you? I suggest you go back and see about accepting some.

Comment: Did you *try* it?

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `++x;` changes the argument `x`. The field `x` is *shadowed*. To modify the field, you would need something like

```
++this.x;
```

Note that the field `x` and the variable `x` are unrelated (apart from having the same name).

Answer (score 0):

Here, It changes the input parameter value x from 5 to 10.

```
line 1 int x = 5;
line 2 public void changeValJava(int x){
line 3    ++x; 
       }
```

int is a primitive variable and at line 2 - its better to refer as Initialization than referring as instance. At line 2, x variable is initialised to 5, and at line 3 x variable is reinitialised to 6 - as in x = x + 1;

The variable x at line 1 can be referred or updated using instance variable of the class or using this keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Like in C, Java also stores the local value of x. So when you take `++x`, it increments that value of `x` that is passed to the function `changeValJava`.
In Java, the 'actual' `x` is the **instance variable** whereas the x in `changeValJava` is just a local variable. These two `x`s are different.

Java doesn't support pointers, to change the 'actual' value, you need to associate the object containing x. Here that object is the self-object, referred by `this` keyword. So, you can write

```
++this.x
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, there is a separate stack for each thread. All the method and its variables are stored in this stack.

Your questions seems to be little bit confusing to me.

If you are asking about **pass by value and pass by reference (pointers in C)**.

Its very clear that **Java supports only pass by value**.

If you are asking, **how java stores method variables and their objects**, then 
**"In java there is a separate stack for each thread, where it stores all the method, method variables and objects"**.